# LoginStatus control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, login-control

Any one help me out, how to work with LoginStatus control in asp.net...

the statu before login should be 'userlogin'
after logged in ,it automatically changes to 'userlogout'

any suggestions??

Comment: It's a valid behavior of this control - show user's current login status. What's the problem with that?

Comment: do you want to change the "text" that is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
<asp:LoginView ID="ctlRightNavbar" runat="server">
   <AnonymousTemplate>
       <a href="/login.aspx" class="navbar">userlogin</a>
   </AnonymousTemplate>
   <LoggedInTemplate>
      <a href="/logout.aspx" class="navbar">userlogout</a>
   </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

This will make a more custom view for you if you do not wish to use LoginStatus. You can read more about the above code sample [here](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3655706/ASPNET-Tip-Using-the-LoginName-and-LoginStatus-Controls.htm).