# ASP.NET LoginStatus control shows "Login" even though logged in

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

In my ASP.NET project, I am using Forms authentication. My main.master using LoginStatus control and web.config is set up for "Forms" authentication mode.

Before I log in, the control shows the text as "Login." After I log in, the control shows the text as "Logout." This is expected. However, after clicking around on a few links within the site, the control suddenly starts showing "Login" although I am still logged in. The session is still alive as some of the pages I visit dumps some session information.

Would appreciate if something can point me in the right direction. Regards.

Comment: You might consider using LoginView for same purpose and skipping use LoginStatus, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279570/loginstatus-control-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

- If you are trying to redirect after setting a Session variable using
  `Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");`
  this may be causing the session token to gets lost, try using the overloaded version of Redirect:`Response.Redirect("~/YourPage.aspx", false);`
- Another problem also may be miss configuration of application pool. If the application pool is configured as a web farm or a web garden (by setting the
  maximum number of worker processes to more than one) and if you're
  not using the session service or SQL sessions, incoming requests will
  unpredictably go to one of the worker processes, and if it's not the
  one the session was created on, it will get lost. 
  The solutions to this is either not to use a web garden if you don't need the
  performance boost, or use one of the out of process session
  providers.

For more information you can check the link of the original article below: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_